# Share memory across multiple application instances

Tags: python, memory-management, nlp

I have a model which takes around 6 Gb memory and I have a 16 Gb machine. Now in this machine, I want to run multiple instances of the python application.

Now, if I instantiate this model for each instance, I'll hardly be able to run 2 instances. However, if we can share this model across instances, there will not be such limitation as apart from this model, the remaining application footprint in around 400 mb for each instance.

So, should I increase the memory of the application or is there a way to share this model across instances.

Comment: Maybe you can try multiprocessing.

Comment: @stamaimer As per my understanding, multiprocessing helps us in leveraging the multiple cores of the machine. How can we use it to share memory across instances.

Comment: Load model, and start separate process for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [multiprocessing — Process-based parallelism](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html). With that you can share your model between processes.

> Managers provide a way to create data which can be shared between
>   different processes, including sharing over a network between
>   processes running on different machines. A manager object controls a
>   server process which manages shared objects. Other processes can
>   access the shared objects by using proxies.